# Can't intercept and manipulate data with Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I tried everything to manipulate the data that is send with a post, but my interceptor 'destroys' the data that I want to send.

The code bellow produces a [object Object] in the payload:

[image: ObjectObject]

```
galahadService.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
return {
    ...config, 
    transformRequest: [
        (data) => {
            console.log(data)

            return data;
        }
    ]
}
}, function (error) {
// Do something with request error
return Promise.reject(error);
})
```

It looks like Axios is trying to send it as form data when manipulating the data, if I leave the data alone it is a normal JSON payload What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does ` console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` help?

Comment: Some function is trying to use an Object as a key, which applies the toString method. Every objects `.toString()` will result in [object Object]

Comment: No that JSON.stringify does not help, it looks like Axios is trying to send it as form data when manipulating the data, if I leave the data alone it is a normal JSON payload

Comment: @skyboyer it is. Thanks!

Comment: I faced the same problem and basically the solution (which is not obvious in the linked question) is to make sure that your "Content-Type" (and "Accept" ) headers are set to "application/json".